# Deserialize nested JSON array using RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, json-deserialization

Having the following json array:

```
[{
"Name": "Component1",
"Count": 2,
"Bulletins": [{
    "ReferenceNumber": "00000A57",
    "Title": "Test test test",
    "PublicationDate": "2014-07-02",
    "List": ["00000A57"]
},
{
    "ReferenceNumber": "10V240000",
    "Title": "Bla bla bla",
    "PublicationDate": "2010-06-04",
    "List": ["10V240000"]
}]
},
{
"Name": "Component2",
"Count": 2,
"Bulletins": [{
    "ReferenceNumber": "00-00-0A-57",
    "Title": "INFORMATION REGARDING BLA BLA",
    "PublicationDate": "2015-05-22",
    "List": ["15-00-89-004",
    "15-00-89-004A"]
},
{
    "ReferenceNumber": "01-02-0B-57",
    "Title": "UNSCHEDULED SUPPLEMENTAL SERVICES",
    "PublicationDate": "2012-09-28",
    "List": ["04-06-01-029",
    "04-26-51-029",
    "04-26-51-029",
    "04-26-51-029",
    "04-26-51-029",
    "04-26-51-029",
    "04-26-51-029"]
}]
}]
```

I'm using the following code to retrieve the `Name` and `Count` values:

```
public class BulletinsItemsName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public List<BulletinsContainer> blt { get; set; }
}

public class BulletinsContainer
{
    public Bulletins Bulletins;
}

public class Bulletins
{
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public string SupersededList { get; set; }
}
```

To run the request i have:

```
var req = request.Execute<List<BulletinsItemsName>>(parameters);
```

And to list values:

```
foreach(var xx in req.Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xx.Name); 
    foreach(var yz in xx.blt) // Object reference not set to an instance of an object
     {
         Console.WriteLine(yz.Bulletins.Title);
     }
}
```

How can I get values for: `ReferenceNumber`, `Title`, `PublicationDate` and `List`? All values are correctly returned for `Name` and `Count` but when I want to get `Bulletins` values the following error is thrown: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: Your model should be a little bit different. See http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Great suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a list of Bulletins instead of BulletinsContainer - It's early morning for me, but I can't see why you need a BulletinsContainer

```
public List<Bulletins> blt { get; set; }
```

I would also recommend, if possible, that you name your classes in their singular form.